# DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox Blue Boarder

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is trivial but it hurts my OCD. Is there any way of removing the blue boarders of a ComboBox added to a DataGridView?

[image]

```
    Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    cmb.HeaderText = "Project"
    cmb.Name = "cmbProject"
    cmb.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
    cmb.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = False
    cmb.Items.Add("0001")
    DGV.Columns.Add(cmb)
```

EDIT: Unrelated to the question but I'm going to add this here in case it helps anyone. This code drops down the ComboBox on first click

```
    Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then
        ' Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
        RemoveHandler combo.Enter, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_Enter)
        ' Add the event handler. 
        AddHandler combo.Enter, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_Enter)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    TryCast(sender, ComboBox).DroppedDown = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `cmb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat`

Comment: Thankyou Lars Tech! A lot of searching before I asked.